# Is there any inbuilt class for editing image in zend framework

Tags: image, zend-framework

I would like to resize and crop image in zend framework, is there any inbuild class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just that simple. There have been some proposals but only [one](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Image+-+Dolf+Schimmel) has made it into the incubator yet.

Comment: The one on Google Code is not the same as the one in the incubator.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this filter will fit your needs:

- [polycaster/Zend_Filter_ImageSize - GitHub](https://github.com/polycaster/Zend_Filter_ImageSize)